# Compile an Excel VBA Script to modify a connection property in another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that contains a macro that i wish to use to update the location of a connection in another workbook. The VBA script creates a folder, populates it with a log file containing data called log.txt and a copy of an excel file that is pre formatted to fill with the data allowing the user to see graphs and a detailed breakdown of the data. it is a door opening log, tracking numbers of times the door has been used.

here is the VBA code I've come up with so far.
note: I did a couple of years programming in C++ but haven't touched it in a decade. I have tried searching around for the code and even recording a macro of the actions I take when refreshing the connection manually. however if I try and use that code it gives a "Run time error 1004" Application defined or object defined error.

Here is the code. The commented out bit at the bottom is the result of the macro recorded from manually altering the connection.

Any help would be greatly received.

```
Sub Lof_File_Macro()
' Log_file_Macro Macro
' Runs script for monthly counts    '
Dim strfolder1, strmonthno, strmonth, stryear, strfoldername, strfile, strmonyr, stlogfile, strfutfile    
'date strings defined using date functions - ofset for 28 days to allow running anytime within 20 days into the next month whilereturning correct month
strmonthno = Month(Date - 28)
strmonth = MonthName((strmonthno), True)
stryear = Year(Date - 28)    

strmonyr = " " & strmonth & " " & stryear
strfolder = "C:\Users\jtaylor7\Desktop\futures\People Counter" & strmonyr
strfile = "Futures People" & strmonyr & ".xls"    

strlogfile = strfolder & "\" & "log" & strmonyr & ".txt"
strfutfile = strfolder & "\" & strfile   

MkDir (strfolder)    

FileCopy "C:\Users\jtaylor7\Desktop\futures\log.log", strlogfile
FileCopy "C:\Users\jtaylor7\Desktop\futures\template.xls", strfutfile    

'Workbooks.Open Filename:=strfutfile
'ActiveWorkbook.Connections.AddFromFile (strlogfile)
'
'     
' Perform data connection modification on file

''    Windows(strfutfile).Activate
'    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("log")
'        .Name = "log"
'        .Description = ""
'  End With
'    Range("$A$1:$H$1").Select
'With Selection.QueryTable
'        .Connection = "TEXT;strlogfile"
'        .TextFilePlatform = 850
'        .TextFileStartRow = 1
'        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
'        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
'        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
'        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
'        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
'        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
'        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
'        .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "/"
'        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
'        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
'        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
'    End With
'    Range("I4").Select
'    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("log").Refresh
''    Windows("Run Me.xls").Activate
    '
End Sub
```

I know its a bit messy, and if anyone needs any further data please ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick.

*Pls update your paths from my testing below*

```
Sub LogFile_Macro()
Dim strFolder As String
Dim strMonthno As String
Dim strMonth As String
Dim strYear As String
Dim strFoldername As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strMonyr As String
Dim strLogfile As String
Dim strFutfile As String
Dim wb As Workbook

'date strings defined using date functions - ofset for 28 days to allow running anytime within 20 days into the next month whilereturning correct month
strMonthno = Month(Date - 28)
strMonth = MonthName((strMonthno), True)
strYear = Year(Date - 28)
strMonyr = " " & strMonth & " " & strYear
strFolder = "C:\temp\People Counter" & strMonyr
strFile = "Futures People" & strMonyr & ".xls"

strLogfile = strFolder & "\" & "log" & strMonyr & ".txt"
strFutfile = strFolder & "\" & strFile

On Error Resume Next
MkDir strFolder
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "cannot create path", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If
On Error GoTo 0

FileCopy "C:\temp\futures\log.log", strLogfile
FileCopy "C:\temp\futures\template.xls", strFutfile

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strFutfile)
With wb.Sheets(1).QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & strLogfile, Destination:=Range("A1:H1"))
    .Name = "log"
    .TextFilePlatform = 850
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "/"
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    .Refresh
End With
Windows("Run Me.xls").Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks very much. Would it be possible to explain why what I was doing was wrong? I understand the differences in the code but am unsure why mine wasn't working. Thanks very much

Comment: Joe you were very close. This line was creating a new connection `ActiveWorkbook.Connections.AddFromFile (strlogfile)` in a stepped process. But your bigger issue was` With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("log")` where you were trying to work with the connection named "log" before naming it as "log"

Comment: Ahh, yeah I can see that causing a problem. There was a connection in the file that is copied called log so the code I used was a modification. Thanks very much for your help i was bumbling about in the dark a bit. Will award the bounty in 22hrs, was well worth it :-)

Comment: @JoeTaylor Thanks Joe. These things can be very fiddly to find. :)